# Regex for catching "/*...*/" style comments in .lua files

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, lua

I'm in the process of updating an addon to a game I'm fond of playing and I'm currently in the process of just cleaning things up a bit. There are lots of comments in various formats, some using the native lua `--[[` and `]]--` and others using `/*` and `*/`, which my IDE (IntelliJ with EmmyLua plugin) doesn't recognize. So far I've got `/\*(.*\n?)*\*/` for pulling the entire comment, `/\*(?=(.*\n?)*\*/)` for pulling the opening "`/*`" and as far as I can tell, the regexp for the closing "`*/`" should be `(?<=/\*(.*\n?)*)\*/`, but IDEA just displays "nothing to show". Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had some luck using the following

**Regex Without Multiline flag**

```
/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//
```

**Same with Multi-line flag**

```
/^\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/+$/m
```

I used / to denote my regex strings.